# Does JDK 1.6 comes with a reference implementation of JAX-RS integrated in it?

Tags: java, service, web, jax-ws, jax-rs

With JDK 1.6, I can implement a JAX-WS based web service without a need to have an external implementation of JAX-WS or even without the need of an external servlet container since JDK 1.6 provides both.

It seems to me that for JAX-RS, the situation is not the same; meaning that to implement a JAX-RS web service, I will need to download the reference implementation (Called Jersey) separately.

Am I correct, or JDK 1.6 comes with Jersey out of the box as well?

Comment: Beware that you are talking about Sun's (well, Oracle's) JDK here: other JDKs may NOT provide a JAX-WS implementation. Generally speaking, you should avoid using a JDK-specific interface implementation, as this makes your code non portable.

Comment: Good point. I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

It's a separate download:

http://jersey.java.net/

https://wikis.oracle.com/display/Jersey/Main